# How can I reproduce a C++ class style get function in C?

Tags: c++, c

I want to reproduce a get style function from C++ in a C program. In `C++`, there can be two functions in a class for assigning the value and setting the value. Is there any equivalent way in `C? Lets say i have following structure:

```
typedef struct test_help
{
    int      a;
    void** numArrays;
    struct test_help *next;  
} help_node, *help;
```

I have function like the following for accessing the value of  structure:

```
int access_int(help damaru) {
    return damaru->a;
}
```

so I can assign the value of integer from the structure:

```
 int y = access_int(damaru);
```

But i want to assign the value to the memeber of structure like:

```
help damaru;
int z=10;
damaru->int = z;
```

I would like to get rid of the use of `->`.  I would like to write a function which is similar to the assign function. I would like to remind you that use of access function in left hand side shows warnings.

Comment: @PaulManta Especially when complemented with an article-less "in `C`" :)

Comment: Don't obscure pointers by typedefing them, it makes it very hard to see what are pointers and what not.

Comment: Why would you need any of this? What's wrong with `damaru->a = 10;`? Short and to the point.

Comment: C isn't C++.  Don't try to force it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo that is why you get a syntax error, the correct way to do this is

```
 damaru->a = z;
```

To make an access function something like this would work

```
 void setA(help inHelp,int inA)
 {
    inHelp->a = inA;
 }
```

Then use

```
 setA(damaru,z);
```

---

Remember you are using C.  C is not object oriented so *there is no direct mapping* of this object oriented feature.

Comment: I believe the OP understands that and it is just an typo for the code correctly does `damaru->a;`.

Comment: but the my question is, if there are some functions i can write instead of those**->** .

Comment: `->` is the way you do it in C.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to twist C into working like C++, they are two languages that are used completely differently. Unless you need to perform more than a simple assignment, just modify the variable directly. Anyway, yes, what you showed it the way to do it:

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
} MyType;

void MyType_SetVal(MyType *mt, int i) {
    mt->val = /* some complex expression involving `i` */;
}
```

Comment: I disagree.  Encapsulation is just as relevant in C as it is in C++, so the arguments for and against have setters and getters are the same for both languages.  In more complex examples, the setter and getter could do something more sophisticated than simply setting a single member variable.

Comment: @Oli Read the answer again, then.

Comment: Sure, but the "don't try to twist C into C++" is what I'm disagreeing with here...

Answer (score 1):

You can define setter function like this.

```
void set_int(help damaru, int value) {
    damaru->a = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `damaru->a = 42;`, or, without the `->`: `(*damaru).a = 42;`